# How to reset the trackbar in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

How do I force the slider in the trackbar to be in the leftmost position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
trackBar1.Value = trackBar1.Minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

does this:

```
trackBar1.Value = trackBar1.Minimum;
```

not work for you ?

Comment: Hmmm, methinks SO's new post detector isn't working very well. I didn't get warned of Johannes' reply before posting mine. At least it looks like we both checked with the compiler before posting :-)